# Implementation of java.io.InputStream.available()

Tags: java, inputstream

Why is this method implemented as follow (or implemented at all) ?

```
public int available() throws IOException { return 0; }
```

It is also stated in the javadoc that this method ***should*** be overidden. Wouldn't have it been better to make it abstract to force programmers to redefine it ?

I think this make the usage of this method quite unsafe in children class because there is no guarantee that this method has been overidden.

Comment: It's almost always a mistake to use `available()` anyway in my experience...

Comment: This is from the Oracle docs: Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.
So making `available()` as abstract might not be a good idea

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand that this method is not reliable (also from my experience). But the fact a 'default' implementation is provided shocked me..